C++ - Impresión de una cadena carácter por carácter en base a puntero con while
Parece funcionar, pero por alguna razón hasta me corrompe el compilador. ¿Qué esta sucediendo?
void print(char *p);

int main(){
    char *pointer;
    cin>>pointer;
    print(pointer);

}

void print(char *p){
    int i = 0;
    while(p+i!=NULL){
        cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;
        ++i;
        // system("pause");
    }
}

Puse la pausa para tratar de entender que ocurre sin mayor éxito

Tu cadena necesita espacio para guardar los caracteres, asi como está char *pointer; apunta a cualquier lugar. Debería ser algo así: char cadena[1024];

cin >> pointer espera que el puntero tenga una dirección válida a un arreglo con suficiente espacio. Sin embargo pointer apunta a un lugar desconocido: no sabes si tiene suficiente espacio o si quiera si tienes permiso. Por suerte a partir de C++20 la librería solo permite escribir en arreglos de tamaño conocido. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Estás experimentando lo que se conoce como comportamiento indefinido (CI). Lo más destacable del CI es que tiene efectos impredecibles: tu programa puede (aparentemente) funcionar, puede no funcionar, puede dar un fallo en tiempo de ejecución, puede no compilar o humorísticamente se dice que puede invocar demonios en tus fosas nasales.
El CI sucede por estar escribiendo información sobre un puntero que no apunta a memoria válida. En c++, cuando una variable no se inicializa ésta se queda con valores indeterminados1, así que tu char *pointer; está apuntando a una dirección de memoria desconocida, que además no tiene espacio de memoria reservado para ser rellenado.
Puedes solucionar este problema de las siguientes maneras:

Lee sobre un std::string: esta solución evita tener que manejar memoria a mano, ya que se encargará el objeto std::string de ello:
void print(const std::string &s) {

    for (const auto &c : s)
        std::cout << c;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    print(s);

    return 0;
}

Puedes ver el código funcionando en Try it online!.
Lee los caracteres uno a uno:
int main() {
    for (char c; std::cin.get(c); )
        std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}

Puedes ver el código funcionando en Try it online!.


1Salvo en determinadas excepciones que no son el tema de este hilo.

Los errores son estos:
En char *pointer; no está inicializado.
En la verificación while(p+i!=NULL) lo que se está haciendo es verificar si el puntero es nulo.
Cuando declaraste int i = 0 e usaste while (*p + i != '\0') iniciaste una suma e incremento que entró en un bucle infinito, ya que *p + i siempre será diferente de '\0'.
*Corrección:
Inicializa el pointer:
char *pointer = new char[60];

Usa '\0' para verificar el final de la string.
while (*p != '\0')

Code
void print(char *p);

int main() {
  char *pointer = new char[60];

  std::cin >> pointer; 

  print(pointer);

  return 0;
}

void print(char *p) { 
  while (*p != '\0') {
    std::cout << *p << std::endl; 
    ++p; 
  }
}

code

Ojo, std::cin no tiene el operador <<.
